# Can't Import Headers for Libpqxx on Windows

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I am having some difficulties understanding how to link the header files of libpqxx.  I have generated the output using CMake and then built the Release x64 version of it using Visual Studio.  When I go to #include the headers, I can't #include them.  According to the documentation, there should be  as the header, but when I try and enter that, it gives me an error.  I have tried to go into the project settings and set the include folder of the built version of libpqxx as an additional include dependency.

Does anyone happen to have any experience with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with linking. You have to add the `include` directory with the header files to the *include path*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was able to get the headers to read, thank you for that information.  I'm struggling now to get the program to build  I don't fully understand how to link to the proper libraries.  I built the program for x64 as I was getting a mismatch error before, but now it's just a full console log of errors.  Do you happen to know of any good resources that could explain library linking and building of C++? 
 Thank you so much!!

Comment: Windows is not my field of expertise, sorry. Typically, you have to link with these `*.lib` files.

Comment: No problem at all, I appreciate the assistance.  I'll have to do some more research around this.  Thank you so so much!!